# Drop different coloured markers on map using Google maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Markers in my code represent vehicles, now what I want to do is to check the status (Moving, Stationary, Deactivated) of a vehicle by the colour (Green, Red, Yellow respectively) of the marker. What I am getting is when I click the button to see all the markers, all the markers appear and are of the same colour (Red) and when I hover mouse over those markers they show '5' which is the last marker in array.
I know I am making some lame mistake, can someone please have a look at my code and tell me what am I missing? There is some mistake in my `for` loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/va87foja/1/

**code snippet (from jsfiddle):**

```js
var map;
var all = [
 {"name": '0', "lat": 24.92650881416285, "lng": 67.10869789123535, "status": 'Deactivated'},
 {"name": '1', "lat": 24.845937391711946, "lng": 66.73162758350372, "status": 'Stationary'},
 {"name": '2', "lat": 24.89372598975854, "lng": 67.08657503128052, "status": 'Deactivated'},
 {"name": '3', "lat": 24.803024353889768, "lng": 67.02959954738617, "status": 'Moving'},
 {"name": '4', "lat": 25.032825073841558, "lng": 66.8778133392334, "status": 'Moving'},
 {"name": '5', "lat": 24.91757686884615, "lng": 67.19997346401215, "status": 'Stationary'}
];
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.89372598975854,67.08657503128052),
   zoom: 11,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });
}

function drop(){
 //end.setVisible(false);
 map.setZoom(10);
 clearMarkers();   
 for (var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
    addMarker(all[j], j * 200);
 }
// stop();
}

function clearMarkers(){
 for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
   markers[j].setMap(null);
   }
   markers = [];
}

function addMarker(position, timeout){
 var icon="";
 for(var k=0; k<all.length; k++)
 {
  var data = all[k];
  switch(data.status){
   case "Stationary":
     icon = "red";
     break;
   case "Moving":
     icon = "green";
     break;
   case "Deactivated":
     icon = "yellow";
     break;
  }
 }
 icon="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + icon + ".png";
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
   title: data.name,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
    }));
   }, timeout);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<center>
 <br><br>
 <input onclick="drop();" type=button value="Show All">
 <br><br>
 <div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:460px;"></div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want something like this:

```js
   var map;
        var all = [
            { "name": '0', "lat": 24.92650881416285, "lng": 67.10869789123535, "status": 'Deactivated' },
            { "name": '1', "lat": 24.845937391711946, "lng": 66.73162758350372, "status": 'Stationary' },
            { "name": '2', "lat": 24.89372598975854, "lng": 67.08657503128052, "status": 'Deactivated' },
            { "name": '3', "lat": 24.803024353889768, "lng": 67.02959954738617, "status": 'Moving' },
            { "name": '4', "lat": 25.032825073841558, "lng": 66.8778133392334, "status": 'Moving' },
            { "name": '5', "lat": 24.91757686884615, "lng": 67.19997346401215, "status": 'Stationary' }
        ];
        var markers = [];

        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.89372598975854, 67.08657503128052),
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            });
        }

        function drop() {
            //end.setVisible(false);
            map.setZoom(10);
            clearMarkers();
            for (var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
                addMarker(all[j], j * 200);
            }
            // stop();
        }

        function clearMarkers() {
            for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                markers[j].setMap(null);
            }
            markers = [];
        }

        function addMarker(data, timeout) {
            var icon = "";

            switch (data.status) {
            case "Stationary":
                icon = "red";
                break;
            case "Moving":
                icon = "green";
                break;
            case "Deactivated":
                icon = "yellow";
                break;
            }

            icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + icon + ".png";

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: { 'lat': data.lat, 'lng': data.lng },
                    map: map,
                    title: data.name,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
                }));
            }, timeout);


        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
}

#map {
            height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input onclick="drop();" type=button value="Show All">
<div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:460px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working here in the fiddle but there is still some issue. Now my markers aren't visible on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did it. There was some issue when I integrated the code provided by @Vadim Gremyachev with my original code but now it's working.

```js
var map;
var all = [
 {"name": '0', "lat": 24.92650881416285, "lng": 67.10869789123535, "status": 'Deactivated'},
 {"name": '1', "lat": 24.845937391711946, "lng": 66.73162758350372, "status": 'Stationary'},
 {"name": '2', "lat": 24.89372598975854, "lng": 67.08657503128052, "status": 'Deactivated'},
 {"name": '3', "lat": 24.803024353889768, "lng": 67.02959954738617, "status": 'Moving'},
 {"name": '4', "lat": 25.032825073841558, "lng": 66.8778133392334, "status": 'Moving'},
 {"name": '5', "lat": 24.91757686884615, "lng": 67.19997346401215, "status": 'Stationary'}
];
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.89372598975854,67.08657503128052),
   zoom: 11,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });
}

function drop(){
 //end.setVisible(false);
 map.setZoom(10);
 clearMarkers();   
 for (var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
    addMarker(all[j], j * 200);
 }
// stop();
}

function clearMarkers(){
 for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
   markers[j].setMap(null);
   }
   markers = [];
}

function addMarker(position, timeout){
 var icon="";
 var data = position;
    switch(data.status){
  case "Stationary":
    icon = "red";
    break;
  case "Moving":
    icon = "green";
    break;
  case "Deactivated":
    icon = "yellow";
    break;
 }
 icon="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + icon + ".png";
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
   title: data.name,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
    }));
   }, timeout);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<center>
 <br><br>
 <input onclick="drop();" type=button value="Show All">
 <br><br>
 <div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:460px;"></div>
</center>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/va87foja/2/